# DOM issue in Safari with buttons

Tags: dom, button, safari, back

I was wondering if anyone has seen this issue before.

I have two button on a webpage. When I navigate away from the page and hit the back button to return the value of one button is placed in the value of the other.

E.g

```
<input class="SmallData" type="submit" id="logButton" value="Log In" tabindex="93"></input>

<input class="btn" type="submit" id="acBtn" value="Detailed Quote"></input>
```

When I come back to the page Detailed Quote replaces Log In  e.g.

```
<input class="SmallData" type="submit" id="logButton" value="Detailed Quote" tabindex="93"></input>
```

There is no JavaScript causing this to happen. I look at the source everything looks fine but I inspect the DOM I can see that the there is a different value.

Is there something about how web kit handles the dom that it gets corrupted when the back button is used?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tested on WebKit nightly? Can you post URL to live example?

Comment: I can't replicate this using your two inputs.  Perhaps you could post the entire page?

Comment: I haven't tested using the nightly web kit build. Unfortunately because of some propitiatory code I can post the full page.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving each input element a name="some_unique_name" attribute -- see if that helps Safari differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

Mght it be because of having two submit buttons...?

Just my "random" suggestion though... :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the same thing happens in Chrome (if you have access to a Windows box) to see if it's a WebKit issue or Safari itself.